# How to promisify a foreach loop

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous, promise

I have this function:

```
remove(data.toString())
function remove(node){
    Item.findByIdAndDelete(node).then(()=>{
        Item.find({parent: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(node)}).select('_id').then((d)=>{
            d.forEach(e => {
                remove(e._id)
            });
        })
    })
}
```

I would like to promisify it so that I can call:

```
remove(data.toString()).then(()=>{console.log('done')})
```

how can I achieve this?
any help would be greatly apprectiated!

Comment: Start by returning a promise from `remove`… then [stop using `forEach`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should:

- *return* each promise that is created in a callback.
- `map` the array of promises that you get from the recursive calls (instead of `forEach`) and pass that array to `Promise.all`
- flatten the promise chain, avoiding nested `then` callbacks.

```
function remove(node) {
    return Item.findByIdAndDelete(node).then(() => {
        return Item.find({parent: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(node)}).select('_id');
    }).then(d => {
        return Promise.all(d.map(e => {
            return remove(e._id)
        }));
    });
}
```

Things may become easier to read when using `async` `await` syntax:

```
async function remove(node) {
    await Item.findByIdAndDelete(node);
    let d = await Item.find({parent: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(node)}).select('_id');
    return Promise.all(d.map(e => remove(e._id)));
}
```